# Download ALL data for an area from OpenStreetMap

Tags: python, openstreetmap, json, file-formats

I am trying to download ALL the OpenStreetMap data for a certain region.  Meaning, I want the roads, the stores, the rivers, the parks, the traffic signals, the bus stops, ... everything.  I'm expecting that results to be big, so I plan do it for a specific administrative area at a time, and sweep the relevant admin areas.  However, if there is a way to retrieve and download all the data for a larger region, I'm interested in that too. I know how to get all the data of one type by using the Overpass-Turbo wizard; for example, to get all the "highway" data in Shinjuku, this worked:

```
[out:json][timeout:25];
{{geocodeArea:Shinjuku}}->.searchArea;
// gather results
(
  // query part for: “highway=*”
  node["highway"](area.searchArea);    
  way["highway"](area.searchArea);
  relation["highway"](area.searchArea);
);
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

Ideally I'd be able to enter "*" in place of "highway" and get everything, but that didn't work.  I could sweep the types, but I can't find a list of all available element types, so I can't do a "highway or station or ..." type command manually either.

> How do I select all kinds of elements?

My current plan is to incorporate that into a Python-based query to get, format, and save the data using a script like the one below.  It's basically the same as the Overpass Turbo wizard query, but note the last line.

```
tokyo_areacode = 3601543125
query = f"""
    (
        // query part for: “railway=station”
        node["railway"="station"](area:{tokyo_areacode});
        way["railway"="station"](area:{tokyo_areacode});
        relation["railway"="station"](area:{tokyo_areacode});
    );
    // print results
    out body;
    >;
    out skel qt;
    """
    api = overpass.API(timeout=900)
    result = api.get(query, responseformat='csv(::id,::lat,::lon,name)')
```

Because I'm getting all the data, I want to save all the data too, and I think JSON is best for me in this case (I'm going to load it into NetworkX).

> How do I write the `responseformat` to save all the tags for all the elements as a JSON?

It may seem like two questions, but it's just one question about how to get ALL the data for an area, and I highlighted the two steps in that process where I can't find any solutions.

Comment: Would https://github.com/Mapkin/osmgraph with https://download.geofabrik.de an option?

Comment: Do not filter by tags at all. Use just bbox filter https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#Bounding_box.

Comment: osmgraph seems perfect for my needs, but from what I can tell it requires imposm.parser, and that requires Python 2.x and linux/Mac...I'm on Win10+Py3.x

Comment: I downloaded the `bpf` file from geofrablik that covers my area, but currently I have no way to read it into python and check what is included.